# How to find out image auto height if the desired width is 1024 in PHP from any sized image?

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, image-resizing, image-resolution

I have an image with an example dimension of 1600x1200, i would like to resize it down to width: 1024 using PHP.

How do i calculate the height if i only know the desired width?

I know this works on the command line but it calculates the height for me:

```
mogrify -resize 1024 someimage.jpg
```

I am looking to calculate the height in code since php doesn't have any functions that do it for you and they all require the height to be specified.

Thanks

Comment: `$new_height = $old_height * $new_width / $old_width;`

Comment: Seems like a rather simple math question involving ratios. The solution is the same regardless of programming language or the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that helped out.